# Is it possible to pass a Service Filter parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I know that with regular Filters you can pass parameters like so:

```
[Filter(param="value")]
public ActionResult Action()
{
    return View();
}

public class Filter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string param { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // do something with your parameter...
    }       
}
```

I have a Service Filter:

```
// MyCustomFilter.cs    
namespace MyNamespace.Filters
{
    public class MyCustomFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public string param { get; set; }

        // The services I'm injecting.
        private ILogger _logger;
        private IM3ObjectRepository _repo;

        public MyCustomFilter(ILogger<MyCustomFilter> logger, IM3ObjectRepository repo)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _repo = repo;
        }

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext ctx)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Filter is working.");

            // Get stuff from object repository, based on passed-in parameter.
        }
    }
}

// Startup.cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    services.AddSingleton<IM3ObjectRepository, M3ObjectRepository>();

    services.AddScoped<M3UISecurityFilter>();

    ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();

    loggerFactory.AddSerilog();

    ...
}

// Example of filter being used.
[ServiceFilter(typeof(MyCustomFilter))]
public IActionResult Action(...)
{
    ...
}
```

The filter has some services injected into it. But each time I use the service I will also be sending in a parameter.

How would I achieve passing in a parameter? I can't find anything online describing how to do it similarly to a regular Filter. Is it even possible for a Service Filter?

Answer (score 12):

[TypeFilterAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.1#dependency-injection) Is defined exactly for this.

It is exactly like **ServiceFilterAttribute** except that it lets you pass constructor parameters that are not necessarily resolved from the IoC Container.

Example:

```
[TypeFilter(typeof(LogFilter), Arguments = new object[] {"myLogger"})]  
[HttpGet("")]
public IEnumerable<Item> Get()
{
    return this.repository.GetAll();
}
```

[This article describes this neatly.](https://www.strathweb.com/2015/06/action-filters-service-filters-type-filters-asp-net-5-mvc-6/)

Answer (score 8):

I have found an alternative:

```
// MyCustomFilter.cs
public class MyCustomFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string param { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext ctx)
    {
        ILogger<MyCustomFilter> logger = (ILogger <MyCustomFilter>)ctx.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(ILogger<MyCustomFilter>));
        IM3ObjectRepository repo = (IM3ObjectRepository)ctx.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IM3ObjectRepository));

        logger.LogInformation("Filter is working.");

        // Get stuff from object repository, based on passed-in parameter.
    }
}

// Example of filter being used.
[MyCustomFilter(param = "value you want")]
public IActionResult Action(...)
{
    ...
}
```

Instead of injecting the services I need, I am asking for them instead.

I'm now able to set and access the parameter I need.

I'm not marking this as the answer, because it doesn't answer the original question. But it does provide an alternative solution.

**NOTE:** The service for the custom Filter being added in *Startup.cs* is of course no longer required. The services that are used (e.g. in this case the object repository and the logger) are of course still required there.

Answer (score 2):

Just try to extend it

```
public class CustomServiceFilterAttribute : ServiceFilterAttribute
{
    public string Param { get; set; }

    public CustomServiceFilterAttribute(Type type)
        : base(type)
    {

    }
}
```

and use

```
[CustomServiceFilterAttribute(typeof(BaseHttpService), Param = "value")]
```

Comment: I edited the question with some more code.
When I tried your suggestion, the compiler complained about the main constructor (_There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter  'type' of 'ServiceFilterAttribute.ServiceFilterAttribute(Type)'_) and about the **OnActionExecuting** method (_MyCustomFilter.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext)': no suitable method found to override_).